# SQL Union without duplicate values for one specific field

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, postgresql-9.1

There're 3 tables **DEVELOPER**, **MANAGER** and **PROJECT**:

```
create table DEVELOPER(id int(4), lastname varchar(40), project_id int(4));

create table MANAGER(id int(4), lastname varchar(40), project_id int(4));

create table PROJECT(id int(4), name varchar(40));
```

The relantionship between PROJECT and DEVELOPER is One-To-Many, and the relantionship between PROJECT and MANAGER is One-To-One.

All last names stored in the database are unique. The manager can be simultaneously a developer on the same project. (his data stored in two tables in this case).

I want to receive list of all the developers and manager on the specific project from my database in the following form:

**id** | **lastname** | **isManager**

I think it would suit the following query:

```
SELECT id, lastname, false AS isManager FROM developer WHERE project_id = 314
UNION 
SELECT id, lastname true AS isManager FROM manager WHERE project_id = 314
```

But I do not want to have two row of manager's data if he is also the developer for the specific project! I want to leave the line where property isManager is true. Please suggest me proper query to resolve this problem!

Comment: any relation between these two tables

Comment: `developer` and `manager` shouldn't be two different tables. You should have one table `person` and a link table stating the role of the person in a project, something like `person(id, firstname, lastname)` and `project_member(person_id, project_id, project_role)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I absolutely agree with you. But in my situation I have to work with this db structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) for that purpose:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(m.id, d.id) AS id  -- m comes first!
     , lastname                    -- lastname consolidated by USING
     , CASE WHEN m.id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS is_manager
FROM   developer d
FULL   OUTER JOIN manager m USING (lastname, project_id)
WHERE  project_id = 314;
```

But first you might consider [@a_horse_with_no_name's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496462/sql-union-without-duplicate-values-for-one-specific-field/16496750#comment23677813_16496462) about your db design.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` to eliminate duplicates:

```
select  id
,       lastname
,       max(IsManager) as IsManager
from    (
        select  id
        ,       lastname
        ,       project_id
        ,       0 as IsManager 
        from    developer 
        union all
        select  id
        ,       lastname
        ,       project_id
        ,       1
        from    manager
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   project_id = 314
group by
        id
,       lastname
```